# Flood of incredibly basic and/or low quality Unity3D questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

This question for example...

[How to enable/disable cameras' effects programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833415/how-to-enable-disable-cameras-effects-programmatically)

(answer .. "enabled = false") is incredibly basic; it's hard to see you could program ANYTHING in Unity if you haven't read enough basic tutorials to do this.

The canonical pedagogical answer is immediately and instantly available on google search; indeed, instantly available in of course many full tutorials (on unity3d.com itself and many other places).

Indeed, this question is at least properly written and so on. There has been a flood of horribly horrible Unity3D questions from new users.

It's like the worst crap from answers.Unity3d.com is migrating to SO, unfortunately.

Should, or even can, anything be done about this?

For example (purely an example) -- there should be added to the site a particular warning "Don't post crap questions" or "Are you SURE this information is not already easily available?", in any case when the `Unity3D` tag is used.

Should something like this be done to address this systemic problem which is developing?  It's sort of a "clear and present danger!"

Comment: Well, if the answer is as easy to find as you say, dupe-close if you found it on SO. In addition, downvote for lack of research. Not sure what/whether anything else can and should be done.

Comment: Yeah.  There is a specific phenomenon beginning on SO, starting about now (it seemed to begin maybe a couple weeks ago).  This is a huge flood of incredibly low quality "Unity3D" questions.  Should (can?) anything be done about this systemic phenomenon?

Comment: *Low Quality Questions about [Insert Tag Here]* Whilst this question is about a specific tag it's more of a general rant that could be applied to pretty much any tag.

Comment: I suppose you could round up a posse to monitor the Unity3D tag over the next few days so these questions at least get closed faster. I can't think of anything else that would do any good: even if you could track down *why* this is happening now (a Unity 3D contest, some other support forum closing, et.), I don't think there's much you can do about it.

Comment: Also: If you really want people not to ask questions like that, you shouldn't give them answers.

Comment: "It's like the worst crap from answers.Unity3d.com is migrating to SO, unfortunately." Go to GDSE sometimes...

Comment: What a great tag; I needed a laugh!  That, and somewhere to dump my left-over down/close votes.

Comment: @MartinJames go take a look at [php] if you feel like you need a facepalm.

Comment: Hi @MartinJames, do you mean the Unity3D tag?  Yes, it is basically hilarious or perhaps tragicomic.  I'd say one of three questions arriving are of this nature ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837322/how-to-create-a-registration-form-in-unity-c-sharp-or-javascript-and-insert-in-m

Answer (score 14):

The problem with Unity3D is how simple it is to use, which is admittedly one of its appeals and strengths. All you need to do is hook up some items in an editor. Paste on some components within the UI that are provided to you by the standard assets. If you're adventurous, you can get something from the asset store or let's go all out and paste something from a Wiki somewhere in your assets folder and drag it onto your GameObject.

I keep being amazed by how far people can get without really doing any programming at all. But eventually they will get stuck. So you'll have to have a look at these weird little text files that seem to do all the magic stuff. But you're an artist who hasn't ever programmed. Or you're a gamer who now "just wants to make games", without really knowing what that means. That is part of the crowd you'll draw in with a solution such as Unity3D. One can only hope that such issues spark an interest in what's going on behind the scenes, but the majority will be out for a quick fix.

I've been struggling with this and some of the other issues Unity3D's unique attributes provide when it comes to good SO questions. I don't however think there is a whole lot we can do on this side other than to live with what comes in and to evaluate it one question at a time. And indeed, Unity3D does not seem to help us out much given the poor quality of their forums and the SO-clone they tried to provide with the Answers site. (I could go on for hours on that situation, and have with some of their employees).

Downvote, close, whatever seems appropriate. On occasion, when the user seems to be struggling with programming at its core, one could suggest in a friendly and non-dismissive manner that the OP take a step back and actually learn how this programming thing works. But other than that I don't really see a solution. But we're most definitely not the only tag facing such issues. And although I may have missed something, I'm not certain that they have found a great solution other than elbow grease.

Comment: "Downvote, close, whatever seems appropriate" I guess that's really all there is to it, Bart.  Yes, in your first two paragraphs you outline *why* Unity particularly suffers this.  (Hopefully the "Slender" phenomenon doesn't strike SO .. there was a while there on answers unity when there was a flood of questions beginning "So I want to Make a Game like slender..." followed by some bizarre question :) )

Comment: indeed I added this .. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314902/a-new-close-reason-basic-instruction-not-an-answer-is-what-is-needed